# Did I something wrong while converting old code to new one

Tags: java, opengl

I've converted old code to new one and deleted ugly code parts, but it isnt working anymore. May you can help me. It would be nice!

OLD ONE - Header

```java
private ArrayList vertexsets;
private ArrayList vertexsetsnorms;
private ArrayList vertexsetstexs;
private ArrayList faces;
private ArrayList facestexs;
private ArrayList facesnorms;
private ArrayList mattimings;
private MtlLoader materials;
private String mtl_path;
```

OLD FUNCTION

```java
if (newline.startsWith("f ")) {
    facecounter++;
    newline = newline.substring(2, newline.length());
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(newline, " ");
    int count = st.countTokens();
    int v[] = new int[count];
    int vt[] = new int[count];
    int vn[] = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        char chars[] = st.nextToken().toCharArray();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        char lc = 'x';
        for (int k = 0; k < chars.length; k++) {
            if (chars[k] == '/' && lc == '/')
                sb.append('0');
            lc = chars[k];
            sb.append(lc);
        }

        StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(sb.toString(), "/");
        int num = st2.countTokens();
        v[i] = Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());
        if (num > 1)
            vt[i] = Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());
        else
            vt[i] = 0;
        if (num > 2)
            vn[i] = Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());
        else
            vn[i] = 0;
    }

    faces.add(v);
    facestexs.add(vt);
    facesnorms.add(vn);
}
```

I've added a new class called Face which holds v, vt and vn.

```java
public class Face {
    public ArrayList<Float[]> normalIndicies;           //vn
    public ArrayList<Float[]> textureCoordIndicies; //vt
    public ArrayList<Float[]> vertexIndicies;           //v
}
```

NEW ONE - Header

```java
protected ArrayList<Vector3f> verticies;
protected ArrayList<Vector3f> normals;
protected ArrayList<Vector3f> textureCoords;
protected LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> material;
protected ArrayList<Face> faces;

protected String mtlLib;
```

NEW ONE - Function

```java
if(line.startsWith("f ")) {
    Face face = new Face();
    face.vertexIndicies = new ArrayList<Float[]>();
    face.textureCoordIndicies = new ArrayList<Float[]>();
    face.normalIndicies = new ArrayList<Float[]>();

    faceCounter++;

    Float[] vertexIndices = new Float[3];
    Float[] textureIndex = new Float[3];
    Float[] normalIndices = new Float[3];
    String[] firstVec = line.split(" ")[1].split("/");
    String[] secondVec = line.split(" ")[2].split("/");
    String[] thirdVec = line.split(" ")[3].split("/");

    for(int i = 0; i < firstVec.length; i++) {
        if(i == 0) vertexIndices[0] = Float.valueOf(firstVec[i]);
        if(i == 1) textureIndex[0] = Float.valueOf(firstVec[i]);
        if(i == 2) normalIndices[0] = Float.valueOf(firstVec[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < secondVec.length; i++) {
        if(i == 0) vertexIndices[1] = Float.valueOf(secondVec[i]);
        if(i == 1) textureIndex[1] = Float.valueOf(secondVec[i]);
        if(i == 2) normalIndices[1] = Float.valueOf(secondVec[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < thirdVec.length; i++) {
        if(i == 0) vertexIndices[2] = Float.valueOf(thirdVec[i]);
        if(i == 1) textureIndex[2] = Float.valueOf(thirdVec[i]);
        if(i == 2) normalIndices[2] = Float.valueOf(thirdVec[i]);
    }

    face.vertexIndicies.add(vertexIndices);
    face.textureCoordIndicies.add(textureIndex);
    face.normalIndicies.add(normalIndices);
    this.faces.add(face);
}
```

Comment: maybe the ugly parts were needed?

Answer (score 0):

The original data was given in Integer format but you expect the data in the new code to be floats. Since this code seems to be part of a obj parser, the correct datatype are Integers. A face line stores indices to other arrays (positions, tex-coords, etc.).

Other comments on the rewrite:

Splitting itself is quite slow and you are splitting the same string three times along the " "(space) symbol. (Not to mention the memory implications of the splitting).

Also the use of loops and if statements looks very strange since this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < firstVec.length; i++) {
    if(i == 0) vertexIndices[0] = Float.valueOf(firstVec[i]);
    if(i == 1) textureIndex[0] = Float.valueOf(firstVec[i]);
    if(i == 2) normalIndices[0] = Float.valueOf(firstVec[i]);
}
```

is the same as

```
vertexIndices[0] = Float.valueOf(firstVec[0]);
textureIndex[0] = Float.valueOf(firstVec[1]);
normalIndices[0] = Float.valueOf(firstVec[2]);
```

just without unnecessary loops and branches.